# PowerApp Collection error due to the letter 'y' in Data Source

Tags: collections, datasource, powerapps

I have created a relatively complex PowerApp where I ran into an issue related to extracting data from a Collection.
The collection is populated by a simple ClearCollect(cachedKPI, '[dbo].[KPI]').
The KPI table has two columns KPIId (unique values and primary key) and KPIName. The first is a int column and the other nvarchar(200).

**When displaying the two columns in a Data Table in PowerApp I noticed that out of a total of 188 rows only 150 was displayed. If I took the dbo.KPI table as the source of the Data Table all 188 columns were displayed as expected.**

I created a new PowerApp without any other context and ran into the same issue.

When I looked closer at the data I saw that row number 151 to 160 had the same KPIName but different KPIId which in itself this is not an issue.
The KPIName of these rows were 'Retention > 90% (no loss of key staff)'.

After having performed various tests I tried to alter the KPIName. I found that if I renamed the KPIName of row 151 to 'a' I could suddenly also see row 151 (but still not 152 to 160) in the collection Data Table, which let me to believe the error might be due to special characters.

**After a lot of testing I found something interesting. If I removed/replaced the 'y' in 'Retention > 90% (no loss of key staff)' everything was working as expected!**

So having renamed the 9 rows called 'Retention > 90% (no loss of key staff)' to 'Retention > 90% (no loss of kek staff)' my PowerApp was suddenly working again.

I am not sure what the actual problem is. Using 'y' in itself does not seem to provide a problem, so it must be some combination of characters.

Has anyone experienced something similar and might be able to provide a solution?

Comment: In case anyone is interested in investigating this issue it seems that the error occurs if you have the character '%' as well as the word 'key' in the KPIName column.